# How to implement a progress bar with TIdTCPClient?

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using **indy 10** and i was wondering how can i implement a progress bar for transfering a file.I tried with onWork events but they are not triggred. Another thing that i find anoying is that the application freezes until the stream is downloaded.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You can make descendant stream class instrumented with progress feedback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a File from internet programatically with an Progress event using Delphi and Indy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184473/download-a-file-from-internet-programatically-with-an-progress-event-using-delph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an IdAntiFreeze component to your form and use it's properties and events to get notified of the progress of the network operations.

Comment: Anytime you have to use `TIdAntiFreeze`, you are usually not using the right design to begin with. In this case, it might be better to move the `TIdTCPClient` into a separate worker thread so the main thread is not blocked during transfers. If that is not an option, then you can at least call the `Update()` method of either the `TForm` or the `TProgressBar` from inside the `OnWork...` events to make sure the progress UI is updated visually without using `TIdAntiFreeze` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the download code into another thread using `TThread` so that your app doesn't freeze while downloading, and have a procedure that you send to `TThread.Synchronize` to update the progress bar. Also, for `OnWork` to be called, you have to call `OnWorkBegin` first, see http://www.borlandtalk.com/image-vp569607.html