# Read and save part of file stream via IdHTTP

Tags: delphi, stream, indy

I want to download a file from a HTTP server via a file stream and only read (and save to a file) the first few lines, say 100. After reading the first 100 lines the file stream must end: so I do NOT want to download or read the entire file.

Below you can find what I have so far. The website is just an example. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

```
const
  myURL = https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/latest_DWML.txt
var
  fs: TMemoryStream;
  http: TIdHTTP; 
begin
  fs := TMemoryStream.Create;
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    fs.Position := 0;
    http.Get(myURL, fs);
    fs.SaveToFile('test.xml');
  finally
    fs.Free;
    http.free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: On a side note, there's no reason to set a newly created stream's position to 0. It's already empty.

Comment: True, but I think I will need it to reach my goal.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641055/download-file-progressively-using-tidhttp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the HTTP server supports byte ranges for the desired URL (via the [`Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) request header), you can request just the specific bytes you want, and that is all the server will send.  You can use the `TIdHTTP.Request.Range` property for that when calling `TIdHTTP.Get()`.  To discover if the server supports byte ranges, use `TIdHTTP.Head()` first to get the URL's headers, and then check if there is an [`Accept-Ranges: bytes`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.5) header present (see the `TIdHTTP.Response.AcceptRanges` property).

If the server does not support byte ranges, you will have to continue using the code you currently have, just make some changes to it:

- Instead of calling `fs.SaveToFile()`, create a separate `TFileStream` object and pass the `TMemoryStream` to its [`CopyFrom()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.CopyFrom) method, that way you can specify exactly how many bytes to save.
- Use the `TIdHTTP.OnWork` event, or use a `TIdEventStream`, or derive a custom `TStream` that overrides `Write()`,  in order to keep track of how many bytes are being downloaded, so you can abort the download (by raising an exception, like `EAbort` via `SysUtils.Abort()`) once the desired number of bytes have been received.

Of course, either approach is **byte oriented** not **line oriented**.  If you need to be line-oriented, and particularly if the lines are variable length, then you will have to use the second approach above, using `TIdEventStream` or a custom `TStream`, so you can implement line parsing logic and save only complete lines to your file, and then abort once you have received the desired number of lines.