# Read and save part of file stream via IdHTTP and IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1

Tags: ssl, delphi-7, indy, idhttp

I want to download a part of a file from a HTTPS server. I have used an Idhttp and an IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL-component. Using the [TIdHTTP.Response.AcceptRanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939318/read-and-save-part-of-file-stream-via-idhttp) property does not seem to work: it downloads the entire file.

If I use IdHTTP1.Head() and IdHTTP1.Response.AcceptRanges I get nothing back: an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TIdHTTP.Response.AcceptRanges` property tells you whether the server accepts byte ranges for a given URL, *after* you have requested the URL.  You have to use the `TIdHTTP.Request.Range(s)` property to actually specify a range when requesting the URL.  You can use `TIdHTTP.Head()` to check the `AcceptRanges` value before then requesting the actual URL data using `TIdHTTP.Get()` with or without a byte range accordingly.

However, if the `AcceptRanges` propery is blank after calling `TIdHTTP.Head()`, then the server simply does not support byte ranges for that URL, so you have no choice but to download the URL data  in its entirety, and just discard whatever portions you don't want from it.  You could use a `TIdEventStream` for that, or a custom derived `TStream` class that overrides the virtual `TStream.Write()` method.  Either approach would allow you to ignore data being downloaded, just keep track of how many bytes are being "written" to your stream, ignoring bytes until you reach the desired starting offset, and then save the remaining data as needed until the desired ending offset is reached.

Comment: Does this mean that the file will be downloaded as a whole but using a TIdEventStream or a custom derived Tstream class will just ignore a part of the file being downloaded?

Comment: @user3757341 yes